# Strange "lea" prefix on wp-json

Tags: json

I've been using wp-json steadily for a couple years now on a headless CMS project and had no problem getting valid JSON back. I set the website to auto-update all themes, plugins, and WP version. I also added some extra plugins to enhance the wp-json:

- WP Rest Api V2 Multiple PostTypes
- REST API Helper
- Custom Post Types

Today, we started getting invalid JSON back with an "lea" prefix string on the beginning of the JSON for some unknown reason, creating invalid JSON. When I remove this "lea" prefix at the beginning of the JSON, the website works normal again.

Where might I look to see where this "lea" is being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. There's a bug in the TotalPress.org Custom Post Types plugin in the file:

wp-content/plugins/custom-post-types/custom-post-types.php

At the top of the file, you will see the mistake:

```
lea<?php
```

When I remove the `lea`, the problem goes away. I'm contacting the plugin developer to let them know. Plugin version was 3.0.12.